# Linux script change file name,folder name and ingridents

Tags: linux, sed

I have a long folder/file structure with bunch of code files in it. some of my files has "x5g6" pattern on their name, on the folder name and also the text inside the files.

e.g

```
/Mycodes
/pp_x5g6
 - vbg_x5g6.cmd
 - x5g6_pp
 - x5g6_pp.ml
```

so on so forth
also if you open `vbg_x5g6.cmd` file you can see there is a code in it and it also has this pattern (e.g function bb_x5g6 = x+ y);

My question is which commands I can use to recursively change `x5g6` into `x5g7`
 on folder, file names and also inside the files?

So far I could only found;

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/x5g6/x5g7/g' {} +
```

but this only changes whatever inside the files not the folder and file names.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a solution already for editing the file contents.

For the file/directory names, I believe the generally accepted answers are to use either a program called [`mmv`](http://www.cgarbs.de/blog/archives/430-mmv-mass-rename-of-files-and-more!.html), (which I, myself, prefer), or one called [`rename`](http://www.tecmint.com/rename-multiple-files-in-linux/)

For the record, this question is a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98070/rename-files-in-directory.

The original there contains an answer also recommending `zmv` (if you're using `zsh` instead of `bash`).

edit: grammar